# Java Web Start sound

Tags: java, audio, applet, java-web-start

I'm modifying an applet to use Java Web Start, using the `applet-desc` option to launch
the essentially-unmodified code.  Everything works great except the sound.  This
applet uses only the simplest applet sound interface, based on `getAudioClip`.

Other jar-based resources (i.e. images) work fine in both cases, and audio clips
that are not in jars but accessed through real URLs are also fine in both cases.

`getResource` is returning an in-Jar URL, and when run as a normal applet everything
is perfect, but in the same jars, run as a JWS applet the clips are silent.

Comment: *"I'm modifying an applet.."*  Since the applet is being modified, why not modify it to use the [Java Sound API](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info)?  Is the applet intended to be free floating? If so, you might also consider converting it to a `JFrame` while you're at it.  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem was confusion over resource URLs.

Real applets can get their sounds from JARs using a general URL that
has getCodeBase() as a prefix, but JWS applets require you to use
getClass().GetResource(..) to construct an explicitly in-resource url.